# How can I simulate a mouseover event with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a star rating system as defined like this:

```
<span class="rating_container"> 
    <span class="star_container">  
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_1" >1<span class="rating">Terrible</span></a>   
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_2" >2<span class="rating">Bad</span></a>
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_3" >3<span class="rating">Bad</span></a>
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_4" >4<span class="rating">OK</span></a>   
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_5" >5<span class="rating">OK</span></a>   
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_6" >6<span class="rating">OK</span></a>   
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_7" >7<span class="rating">Good</span></a>   
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_8" >8<span class="rating">Good</span></a>   
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_9" >9<span class="rating">Excellent</span></a>   
        <a rel="nofollow" href="" class="star star_10" >10<span class="rating">Excellent</span></a>  
    </span> 
</span>
```

Each individual star is colored when a mouseover happens. How can I simulate this with jquery? For instance I'd like to mouseover star 5.  This is what I've tried:

```
     $('.star.star_5').addClass('active');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Gonna point out the obvious but if the class .active doesnt have the styles to light up that star then even correcting the selector format will still not work. And there's no :hover psuedo event that will remain triggered (mouseover is a one shot). I'd need to see your css styles for the star to see what you're doing.

Comment: Here's an example of what I think you're trying to accomplish. I hope this is helpful, if so I can post an answer later when I return; if not just ignore :) and good luck. http://jsfiddle.net/Z8d95/ (using add/remove classes to simulate mouseover and not :hover)

Comment: You don't have a class 'active' defined. Try using "hovered" instead. `$('.star.star_5').addClass('hovered');`

Comment: @Paul Was my answer the one that worked? If so I'll post as an actual answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
$(".star_5").trigger('mouseover');
```

This will trigger the mouseover action whatever it happens to be, rather than emulating it, offering a measure of future-proofing against changes to the mouseover handler.

Comment: Oh, didn't see your answer before posting. This is essentially the same.

Comment: Indeed, the nett effect will be identical. I prefer to use `.trigger()` because, in lengthy scripts, it gives another search opportunity.

Comment: This will work if he defined the style change actions in a mouseover event, but it looks like he's just using `:hover` in his CSS.

Comment: @IanW, I don't think so. He appears to want to add/remove his classname `active`. That's not the same thing as invoking CSS pseudo-class `:hover`. I'm sure the OP will be able to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is

```
$('.star.star_5').addClass('active');
```

**Note** the no-space between `.star` and `.star_5` and the `_` in `star_5`. (Thanks [@wirey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246524/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouseover-event-with-jquery/14246552#comment19768194_14246552))

Comment: NP :)  @Paul is there anyway for you to create a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what your issue is

Answer (score 0):

In CSS (which is what jQuery selectors are based on), `.class1 .class2` means "an element with class2 that has an ancestor with class1". This is not what you want. You want `.class1.class2` which means "an element with both class1 and class2":

```
$('.star.star_5').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to simulate an event: You can trigger JavaScript events using parameterless forms of the corresponding jQuery functions. For example:

```
$('.star.star_5').mouseover();
```