# How to show some tooltip text when page opens?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In this code, I have created a tooltip to show some text when the `updateState` function will be called in HTML file on some mouseover event (I haven't mentioned that).

This works correctly but the text appears only when I hover the mouse over some particular space of the webpage. I want that some text should be there when the webpage opens and when I hover the mouse at some space the initial text should be disappeared and the hovering text should be shown.

How can I do that?

```js
methods: {
  updateState: function() {
    function showTooltip(text) {
      let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
      tooltip.innerHTML = text;
      tooltip.style.display = "block";
    };
    showTooltip('Some text')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip" display="none" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have any external css applying styles to your #tooltip?

Comment: Yes. I have applied external css

Comment: and isn't this external css setting `visibility:hidden`, `opacity:0` or some `transform` to your  #tooltip? This would explain why your `display:block` is not enough

Comment: The signature of `showTooltip` doesn't match what you're passing it. Either way, if the functionality of the tooltip is shared, consider moving the tooltip logic out of the `updateState` method and into a separate component that can be controlled programmatically (like on page load, or some other event).

Comment: let me send it to you......```#tooltip {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align : center;
  padding : 1em;
  width  : 2em;
  height : 2em;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
opacity: 1;
color: gainsboro;
text-shadow: 3px 1px blue;
font-size:360%;
top: 105px;
left:500px;
text-indent: 0%;
right: 80px;
border-radius: 100%;
}```

Comment: @chazsolo I have update the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I simulate a mouseover event with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246524/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouseover-event-with-jquery)